# Restrict or extend an enum in dart

Tags: dart, enums, extend, restrict

I'm working with dart and let's say I have an enumeration (potentially really long) that I cannot modify:

```dart
enum Animal {
  cat,
  dog,
  lion,
  tigger,
}
```

Is it possible to restrict this enum, I would like to obtain

```dart
enum DomesticAnimal {
  cat,
  dog,
}
```

with `DomesticAnimal.cat` still being an `Animal` ?

---

Also, is it possible to extend it to obtain

```dart
enum LivingCreature {
  cat,
  dog,
  lion,
  tigger,
  tree,
  flower,
}
```

where `LivingCreature.cat` still being an `Animal` ?

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible. Enums are pretty restrictive in dart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is currently nothing like that in Dart. An enum value object belongs to exactly one enum type.
There is also no way to create new type which contains just some instances of other types.

Comment: That is so sad :( Thank you for you answer !