# Possibility of enum union in dart?

Tags: dart, enums, union-types

Somewhat related to, but still different from [Restrict or extend an enum in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66038514/restrict-or-extend-an-enum-in-dart) I would like to ask: Would it be possible to create unions of enums in dart? Something like

```
enum Animal {
  cat,
  dog,
}

enum Plant{
  tree,
  flower,
}

// and then define their union as (typescript-like union syntax for no reason)
enum LivingCreature = Animal | Plant;

// such that its values are
LivingCreature.values = [LivingCreature.cat, LivingCreature.dog, LivingCreature.tree, LivingCreature.flower];
```

Since enums are something like constant sets, a set union at compile time and thus the definition of the union-type enum should be possible, right? (Although, I know, values have indices, so it's not a set technically.)

Comment: The answer is the same as in the question you linked. Would the question to this answer be different, the question to the answer you linked would be wrong.

Comment: Nope. "An enum value object belongs to exactly one enum type. There is also no way to create new type which contains just some instances of other types." In my example `LivingCreature.cat`and `Animal.cat`are different objects belonging to different types. So I don't see that answer by lrn applying to my question.

Comment: I would add that you'd be right if I did intend to use `LivingCreature.cat`as a `Animal.cat`(or vice versa, I don't know?), but I don't. (Which might take some of the potential usefulness out of the concept anyway...)

Comment: It's not possible.  You presumably could do it with code generation.  Do you have a compelling reason why you'd want this if there'd be no easy way to convert an `Animal` constant to a corresponding `LivingCreature` one?

Comment: I'm asking out of curiosity, wondering whether it's possible to avoid the seemingly unnecessary code duplication (and ensuing problems like forgetting to modify `LivingCreature` when modifying `Animal` if you create the union yourself via copy and paste). Code generation would be the obvious workaround, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could potentially do is create a class `LivingCreature` and have `Animal` and `Plant` enums implement this class.

In dart 3.0, you will be able to add a [`sealed` modifier](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/main/accepted/future-releases/class-modifiers/feature-specification.md) to the `LivingCreature` class which should allow you to get exhaustiveness checking on switches over variables of type `LivingCreature`.

```dart
sealed class LivingCreature {
  static const List<LivingCreature> values = [...Animal.values, ...Plant.values];
}

enum Animal implements LivingCreature { cat, dog }
enum Plant implements LivingCreature { tree, flower }

void main() {
  LivingCreature creature = Animal.cat;
  switch (creature) {
    case Animal.cat:
      print('cat');
    case Animal.dog:
      print('dog');
    case Plant.tree:
      print('tree');
    case Plant.flower:
      print('flower');
  }
}
```